# iOS: how to reduce size of large PNG files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5, png

I'm currently optimizing my iOS app for *the new iPad*. Unfortunately by adding launch images for the iPad retina display the size of my *ipa* grows from 1.2MB to 5.5MB, mainly because of the two PNG images in 1536 x 2008 (portrait) and 2048 x 1496 (landscape). The size of these images are respectivly 1.9MB and 1.7MB.

The portrait can be seen here: http://uploads.demaweb.dk/iPadPortrait.png.

As you may notice, the background is a fixed pattern but sadly it seems that this is not very compressible. I've further tried to compress the images using [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/), but it does not make any difference after Xcode has compressed the images during the archive. Searching the web I've noticed, that some people are dissuading to turn off PNG compressing in Xcode.

Are there anything I can do? It is not a solution to change the pattern in the image to a solid color, as it should look like the background in my iOS view. But it seems odd, that supporting *the new iPad* increase the size by ~4MB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ive struggled with this too, unfortunately not much can be done.

> In an effort to dramatically increase drawing performance of iOS apps,
>   Xcode re-compresses PNG files as it builds. It premultiplies the alpha
>   channel and byte swaps the red, green and blue channels to be
>   sequenced blue, green and red. The result is optimised for iOS’s
>   purpose, but as a side effect, ImageOptim’s work gets undone…

[Source](http://bjango.com/articles/pngcompression/)

Comment: That exactly the same source I found -- they recommend NOT disabling the compression in Xcode. Maybe iOS users from now on should expect the size of app being drastic increased.

Comment: @DennisMadsen I agree completely, now since the 'new iPad' is now retina display imagine how large apps will get when you need to put in HD graphics for the iPad. I hope apple realizes this and makes changes.

Comment: Maybe this is why the [over-the-air download limit has been increased from 20MB to 50MB](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/03/07/apple-boosts-over-the-air-app-store-download-limits-to-50-mb/).

Comment: I think the "rendering" part is mischaracterisation of the issue. GPU doesn't support formats like paletted 8 bit, so the conversion must be done before rendering (most likely when PNG is decompressed), and hence can't affect *rendering* speed. Conversion from 8-bit/RGB/RGBA to ARGB is trivial and probably done at RAM speed (Gb/s). OTOH larger file to read from disk and more data to decompress may have bigger impact.

Comment: Here's benchmark showing that "dramatically increase drawing performance" does not happen: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/ — *drawing* performance is the same for all formats, even JPEG (and smaller files load faster, regardless of format).

Answer (score 9):

I was able to get it down to 633KB with [pngquant](http://pngmini.com) (64 colors with slight dithering, which is barely noticeable on regular screen, and should be absolutely invisible at Retina resolution) and ImageOptim.

Yes, you will need to [disable Xcode's conversion](http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html) to avoid Xcode inflating files by converting them to ARGB.

***NB:*** the article quoted in the accepted answer provides **no benchmarks** at all for the claimed speed difference.
It also contains correction that it **is** possible to optimize images with ImageOptim for iOS apps.

Comment: Is it safe to disable the PNG compression in XCode? Would a PNG compressed in XCode load faster on the iOS device (even if it's size is higher)? If so, it is a trade-off between performance and app size.

Comment: It is certainly safe, since iOS supports standard PNGs. I've commented on the earlier answer that I think performance benefit of iOS-ARGB format is overblown, because RGBA<->ARGB conversion is trivial. OTOH loading and decompressing more data is not so trivial, so I'd say much smaller file is faster regardless of format.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using a great tool called [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html)

It incorporates a number of tools inside which crush your png files significantly (in my case it was between 25% to 50%).

One thing to remember is to disable Xcode's PNG optimization (as explained on the website)

EDIT:
Simply drag the images to the imageOptim window and the optimization will start automatically

Comment: ImageOptim for regular GUI elements, then add ImageAlpha for any large textures / backgrounds and you get amazing size reductions