# iOS iPAD launch PNG image 5MB too big

Tags: ios, ipad, png, ipa

the launch image is 1536x2048. it shows as 5MB in my folder. (launch image cannot use jpg.)

After I create IPA file, and open the IPA file package contents. I find my launch image size to be 5.2MB.

How do I reduce this SIZE????

1. I use imageOptim to reduce png from 5bm to 2mb. But xcode build option "compress png" actually undo that work. If I disable png compression, does it noticeably affect anything in my app?
2. Even 2MB is still too big. How can I reduce the final png inside IPA to be smaller? like 1MB max? Without sacraficing image quality?

Doesn't make any sense just a PNG launch image would force my app to be size 2MB already.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a similar question : [How to reduce filesize of gradient PNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409931/how-to-reduce-filesize-of-gradient-png)

And a service who providades that kind of service (minimize the size of your png file) https://tinypng.com/

Edit

And finally  a question like yours:

[iOS: how to reduce size of large PNG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623334/ios-how-to-reduce-size-of-large-png-files)

Comment: that is gradient image. Mine is colorful image

Comment: Even I reduce PNG to 2MB with png compression. It is still too large for just a launch image

Comment: According to your comment, at least one of my  links were useful? (tinypng)?

Answer (score 0):

https://tinypng.com/

this does lossy compression pretty well for launch image there is no noticable difference.

It reduces 5MB file down to 1MB